# Integrate OSGi with WildFly-8.2.0.Final

Tags: jboss, osgi, wildfly, wildfly-8

I would like to know the steps to integrate OSGi with WildFly-8.2.0.Final.
I have followed https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBOSGI/Getting+Started?_sscc=t but it is for older version and thrown exceptions on startup.

Please share if you ave any idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OSGi is no longer part of WildFly distribution.

However, community member Arcadiy Ivanov picked up the projected and released compatible version for WildFly 8.2

see http://ivanov.biz/2015/jbosgi-for-wildfly-8-2-released/ for more